# Copy table row to another table row jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I see many others questions that seem like mine, but none of them corresponding to my need. Behold my 3 goals :

1. If I click on checkbox row of **tableFirst** remove this row and copy it  **to tableSecond** row
2. **Remove and Return ** this row of **tableSecond to tableFirst** after clicking on checkbox of **tableSecond** row
3. Once the row is return to **tableFirst** I should be able **to return it to tableSecond** again after clicking on his checkbox, this action should be vise versa

I successfully realize goal 1 and goal 2

1. Goal 1

   ```
   jQuery('.copy-one').on('click', function(e) {
   if($(this).is(':checked',true)) {
   $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function(){ 
   $(this).remove();
   });
   $(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo('#tableSecond>tbody');
   }

   })
   ```
2. Goal 2

   ```
   $('#tableSecond').on('click','.copy-one',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function(){ 
   $(this).remove();
   });
   $(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo('#tableFirst>tbody');
   })
   ```
3. I am stuck at goal 3.

Please help realize goal 3, my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8ayrs3ed/5/

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/clone/ when cloning add events also to be cloned `.clone(true, true)`

Comment: the problem with simply cloning the events is, the copy direction is hard-coded into the click handler (#tableFirst to #tableSecond). If you simply clone the event, it would paste it back into itself. Instead, attach the listener for the event on a given selector at the nearest static container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I notice, in #tableSecond, you're using event delegation. As you should, given that the event you're listening to is attached to a non-existent (at start) DOM node. The issue you're having is that you remove that DOM node from the first table, stick it in the second, and the second one's event handler, being delegated, catches it.

But in the first table, you are listening to the events at the class level. Instead, listen at #tableFirst.

```
jQuery('#tableFirst').on('click', ".copy-one", function(e) {
  if($(this).is(':checked',true)) {
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function(){ 
      $(this).remove();
    });
     $(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo('#tableSecond>tbody');
  }
})
```

Event delegation is a perpetual gotcha. When you remove that DOM node form the first table, it is no longer handling its events. Thus you should listen at the container, and simply have IT manage inner events for dynamic elements.

To see it in action: [your updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/mqcu9nga/1/)

Comment: Nah. You were already there with the second table's code -- you simply needed to look at the bigger picture a little differently. Well done, and good luck!